# Extracting XML Data with Foreach Loops, Results Inconsistent

Tags: php, xml, foreach, domdocument

I am extracting XML data using `DOMDocument` and `foreach` loops. I am pulling certain attributes and node values from the XML document and creating variables with that data. I am then echoing the variables.

I have successfully completed this for the first portion of the XML data that lives between the `<VehicleDescription` tags. However, using the same logic with data within the `<style>` tags, I have been having issues. Specially, the created variables won't echo unless they are in the `foreach` loop. See the code below for clarification.

My php:

```
<?php

  $vehiclexml = $_POST['vehiclexml'];

  $xml = file_get_contents($vehiclexml);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadXML($xml);

   //This foreach loop works perfectly, the variables echo below:

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('VehicleDescription') as $vehicleDescription){
    $year = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('modelYear');
    $make = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('MakeName');
    $model = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('ModelName');
    $trim = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('StyleName');
    $id = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('id');
    $BodyType = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('altBodyType');
    $drivetrain = $vehicleDescription->getAttribute('drivetrain');
    }

   //This foreach loop works; however, the variables don't echo below, the will only echo within the loop tags. How can I resolve this?

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('style') as $style){
    $displacement = $style->getElementsByTagName('displacement')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }


  echo "<b>Year:</b> ".$year;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b>Make:</b> ".$make;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b>Model:</b> ".$model;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b>Trim:</b> ".$trim;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b>Drivetrain:</b> ".$drivetrain;
  echo "<br>";

  //Displacement will not echo
  echo "<b>Displacement:</b> ".$displacement;

?>
```

Here is the XML file it is pulling from:

```
<VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2019" MakeName="Toyota" ModelName="RAV4" StyleName="LE" id="1111"  altBodyType="SUV" drivetrain="AWD">
  <style modelYear="2019" name="Toyota RAV4 LE" passDoors="4">
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <model>RAV4</model>
        <style>LE</style>
        <drivetrain>AWD</drivetrain>
        <displacement>2.5 liter</displacement>
        <cylinders>4-cylinder</cylinders>
        <gears>8-speed</gears>
        <transtype>automatic</transtype>
        <horsepower>203</horsepower>
        <torque>184</torque>
     </style>
</VehicleDescription>
```

Any help or insight as to why variables from the first foreach loop echo but variables from the second don't would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post an alternative solution to the way you've fixed this.

As you've, there are a couple of `<stlye>` tags, this means that the `foreach` will attempt to use all style tags.  But as you know that you are after the contents of the first tag only, you can drop the `foreach` loop and use the `item()` method...

```
$displacement = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style')->item(0)
        ->getElementsByTagName('displacement')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

This also applies to how you fetch the data from the `<VehicleDescription>` tag.  Drop the `foreach` and use

```
$vehicleDescription = $dom->getElementsByTagName('VehicleDescription')->item(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was within the XML document.

Within the `<style>` tags was another set of `<style>` tags. Changing the name of the second set solved this issue.